How do I change the style of labels in HighlightMesh
I'd like to have different styles for indicating elements in a mesh.
Here is an example:
chExample = ConvexHullMesh[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"]];
HighlightMesh[chExample, {Labeled[0, "Index"], Labeled[1, "Index"]}]


I'd like to highlight the edges and vertices differently.  Labeled has the Option LabelStyle:
HighlightMesh[chExample, {Labeled[0, "Index", LabelStyle -> Red], 
  Labeled[1, "Index"]}]


The vertex labels have disappeared.  I've tried other things like Directive, but it doesn't work.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

It looks like HighlightMesh is not supporting the full specification of Labeled.
However, you can manually provide styled labels for each of the cell using MeshCellLabel:
cellLabels[mesh_, i_, style__] := (# -> Style[Last@#, style]) & /@
  MeshCellIndex[mesh, i]

BoundaryMeshRegion[chExample, MeshCellLabel -> 
  cellLabels[chExample, 0, Red, Large, Bold]~Join~
   cellLabels[chExample, 1, Blue]]



Nice solution. Thanks @Domen


See the previous answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/308394/72111

chExample = ConvexHullMesh[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"]];

HighlightMesh[chExample, {Labeled[0, "Index", "Centroid", 
   Style[#, Red, 14, FontFamily -> "Times", Background -> White] &], 
  Labeled[1, "Index", "Centroid", 
   Style[#, Blue, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     Background -> LightGreen] &], Style[2, LightGreen]}]



Thanks @cvgmt (I looked but couldn't find an associated previous question)
